# Separate complex categorical columns

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I am trying to separate several categorical variables in a dataframe. There is nothing complicated here: separate () with a separator "|". However, my dataframe looks something like this:

```
dftest = data.frame(id = 1:3,
                VAR1  = c("oui", "non", "oui"),
                VAR2  = c("2009", "2007", "2018"),
                VAR3 = c("Autre: 5 | Soutien: 32 | Direction: 5","Soutien: 20 | Direction: 6", "Autre: 10 |  Direction: 4"),
                VAR4 = c("Form: 0.8 | Dev: 0.9 | RD: 0.4 | Invest: 1 | TI: 0.3", "Form: 0.8 | Dev: 0.9 | Invest: 1 | TI: 0.7", "Dev: 1.0 | Invest: 1.2 | TI: 0.5"),stringsAsFactors = F)
```

For the moment I apply the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
dt2<- reduce(seq_along(dt),
                 .init = dt,
                 ~ .x %>% separate(names(dt)[.y],
                                   sep = '\\|',
                                   into = paste0(names(dt)[.y], '_' , seq(1 + max(str_count(dt[[.y]], '\\|'), na.rm=TRUE))),
                                   fill = 'right'
                 )
)


> print (dt2)
  id_1 VAR1_1 VAR2_1 VAR3_1 VAR3_2 VAR3_3 VAR4_1 VAR4_2 VAR4_3 VAR4_4 VAR4_5
1  1  oui  2009  Autre: 5  Soutien: 32  Direction: 5  Form: 0.8  Dev: 0.9  RD: 0.4  Invest: 1  TI: 0.3
2  2  non  2007 Soutien: 20  Direction: 6  <NA>  Form: 0.8  Dev: 0.9  Invest: 1  TI: 0.7  <NA>
3  3  oui  2018  Autre: 10  Direction: 4  <NA>  Dev: 1.0  Invest: 1.2  TI: 0.5  <NA>  <NA>
```

I still have two problems:

- The cells contain a "sub-variable" heading
- Each row does not have the same number of modalities on the variables to be separated, which leads to mixtures.

I am actually trying to get the following table:

```
  id VAR1 VAR2 VAR3_Autre VAR3_Soutien VAR3_Direction VAR4_Form VAR4_Dev VAR4_RD VAR4_Invest VAR4_TI
1    1    oui   2009    5    32   5   0.8   0.9   0.4   1   0.3
2    2    non   2007    NA    20    6   0.8   0.9    NA   1   0.7
3    3    oui   2018    10    NA   4    NA    1.0    NA    1.2    0.5
```

I have a lot more difficulty in seeing how to proceed here.
Does anyone have a solution for this situation?

Thank you very much :-).

---

I am continuing my work with this function:

- I made it generic so that it applies to all variables that have a separator.
- I am now trying to transform it so that it deals with different cases.

I have an initial dataframe of type :

```
    dataframe_init <- data.frame(var1 = c("a test | b", "a test | c bla", "b", ""), var2 = c("a blo :2 | b : 12", "a blo :3 | c bli : 6", "b : 4", ""), var3 = c("yes", "no", "", "yes"))
```

I want to get a dataframe of type :

```
    dataframe_fin <- data.frame(var1.a.test = c ("yes", "yes", "no", ""), var1.b = c("yes", "no", "yes", ""), var1.c.bla = c("no", "yes", "no", ""), var2.a.blo = c("2", "3", "0", ""), var2.b = c("12", "0", "4", ""), var2.c.bli = c("0", "6", "0", ""),var3 = c("yes", "no", "", "yes"))
```

I  have tried several scripts for the separation function but none of them work correctly. I'm here:

```
        fun <- function(s, nm = character(0)) {
      if (length(grep("[|]", s)) > 0) {
        lapply(strsplit(s, "[|]"), function(z) {
          purrr::map_dfc(strsplit(trimws(gsub(":", "|", z)), "[|]"), function(y) {
            if (length(y) == 2) {
              setNames(data.frame(y[2]), paste(c(nm, y[1]), collapse = "_"))
            } else {
              df <- setNames(data.frame(0), paste(c(nm, y[1]), collapse = "_"))
              df[df == 0] <- ifelse(nchar(gsub("[^_]*_", "", names(df))) > 0, "yes", "")
              df
            }
          })
        })
      } else {
        list(setNames(data.frame(ifelse(nchar(s) > 0, "yes", ""), nm)))
      }
    }
```

With its application (here for the example I check 1 but in my real dataframe I use it to check that there are at least 10 "|" :

```
    colsep <- which(sapply(dataframe_init, function(x) is.character(x) && sum(grepl("[|]", x)) >= 1))
    
        dataframe_fin2 <- dataframe_init %>%
      mutate(across(c(names(dataframe_init)[colsep]), ~ fun(., cur_column()))) %>%
      unnest_wider(c(names(dataframe_init)[colsep]), names_sep = ".") %>%
      mutate(across(2:ncol(.), ~ type.convert(., as.is = TRUE)))
```

I obtaine this :

```
          `var1.var1_a test` var1.var1_b `var1.var1_c bla` `var2.var2_a blo ` `var2.var2_b ` `var2.var2_c bli ` var3 
      <chr>              <chr>       <chr>                          <int>          <int>              <int> <chr>
    1 yes                yes         NA                                 2             12                 NA "yes"
    2 yes                NA          yes                                3             NA                  6 "no" 
    3 NA                 yes         NA                                NA              4                 NA ""   
    4 NA                 NA          NA                                NA             NA                 NA "yes"
```

I can't seem to put "No" instead of "Na" for organized variables like "var1". Do you have any idea how to unblock me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```r
fun <- function(S, nm = character(0)) lapply(
  strsplit(S, "[|]"), 
  function(z) purrr::map_dfc(
    strsplit(trimws(z), ": +"),
    function(y) setNames(data.frame(y[2]), paste(c(nm, y[1]), collapse = "_"))))
```

Because of your comment regarding `"Research and Development"`, I've modified the data slightly to show this handling the embedded spaces:

```r
dftest <- structure(list(id = 1:3, VAR1 = c("oui", "non", "oui"), VAR2 = c("2009", "2007", "2018"), VAR3 = c("Autre: 5 | Soutien: 32 | Direction: 5", "Soutien: 20 | Direction: 6", "Autre: 10 |  Direction: 4"), VAR4 = c("Research and Development: 0.8 | Dev: 0.9 | RD: 0.4 | Invest: 1 | TI: 0.3", "Form: 0.8 | Dev: 0.9 | Invest: 1 | TI: 0.7", "Dev: 1.0 | Invest: 1.2 | TI: 0.5")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

From here:

```r
dftest %>%
  mutate(across(c(VAR3, VAR4), ~ fun(., cur_column()))) %>%
  unnest(c(VAR3, VAR4)) %>%
  mutate(across(matches("^VAR[34]"), ~ type.convert(., as.is = TRUE)))
# # A tibble: 3 × 12
#      id VAR1  VAR2  VAR3_Autre VAR3_Soutien VAR3_Direction `VAR4_Research and Development` VAR4_Dev VAR4_RD VAR4_Invest VAR4_TI VAR4_Form
#   <int> <chr> <chr>      <int>        <int>          <int>                           <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>       <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1     1 oui   2009           5           32              5                             0.8      0.9     0.4         1       0.3      NA  
# 2     2 non   2007          NA           20              6                            NA        0.9    NA           1       0.7       0.8
# 3     3 oui   2018          10           NA              4                            NA        1      NA           1.2     0.5      NA
```

The `type.convert` mutate is because I'm assuming you want "numbers"; it is not required for the extraction.

Comment: Thank you very much!
It works very well!
However, I replaced "[: ]+" with "\\: +" because I want the two "characters" to be combined. In my example I have simplified the strings present with the ":". In some because they are strings with spaces. For example "Research" is actually "Research and Development".

However when I use "\\: +" it creates twice each column. Once with the good value, and the other with a null value. I don't understand why.

Comment: See my edit, that better handles the embedded spaces.

Comment: Thanks :-).
The result is the same. It duplicates all the columns for me. Each column is duplicated with "NA" in the second.
In the end I added a :
df[, apply(df, 2, function(x) !all(is.na(x)))]
to remove the empty columns it creates for me.
Maybe it's a bug on my side. I don't know...

Comment: Not sure, it's not present in this data, hope you're able to work with it enough.

Answer (score 0):

in Base R:

```
fn <- function(x, df){
  if(any(grepl(":", df[[x]]))){
    a <- paste(gsub("^|\\s+\\|\\s+", paste0("\n",x,'_'),df[[x]]),collapse='\n\n')
    read.dcf(textConnection(a), all = TRUE)
  }
  else df[x]
}

do.call(cbind, lapply(names(dftest), fn, dftest))

 id VAR1 VAR2 VAR3_Autre VAR3_Soutien VAR3_Direction VAR4_Form VAR4_Dev VAR4_RD VAR4_Invest VAR4_TI
1  1  oui 2009          5           32              5       0.8      0.9     0.4           1     0.3
2  2  non 2007       <NA>           20              6       0.8      0.9    <NA>           1     0.7
3  3  oui 2018         10         <NA>              4      <NA>      1.0    <NA>         1.2     0.5
```

In a base R pipe:

```
Map(\(x,y)if(all(!grepl(":", x))) paste0("\n", y,":", x) else
   gsub("^|\\s+\\|\\s+", paste0("\n",y, "_"),x), df, names(df))|>
   do.call(paste, args = _)|>
   paste(collapse = '\n\n')|>
   textConnection()|>
   read.dcf(all = TRUE)

  id VAR1 VAR2 VAR3_Autre VAR3_Soutien VAR3_Direction VAR4_Form VAR4_Dev VAR4_RD VAR4_Invest VAR4_TI
1  1  oui 2009          5           32              5       0.8      0.9     0.4           1     0.3
2  2  non 2007       <NA>           20              6       0.8      0.9    <NA>           1     0.7
3  3  oui 2018         10         <NA>              4      <NA>      1.0    <NA>         1.2     0.5
```